# Java: Getting the total sum of values outputted by a variable

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, sum

I'm sorry if I sound confusing with my title but I am an extreme beginners with programming. My homework assignment was to display the number of days a person has worked with each day's pay doubling (day 1: $1.00, day 2: $2.00, day 3: $4.00, etc..). I have to display the pay they earned for each day along with the total pay they earned for all of the days.

I can't figure how I get the sum of all the pays earned for all the days worked. Help?

```
for ( int daysWorked = 1; daysWorked <= numDaysWorked; daysWorked++) {
    System.out.println("Pay for day #" + daysWorked + ": " + formatter.format(amount));

    amount =  daysWorked * 2;

    totalPay = ?? ;
}
System.out.println("\nTOTAL PAY FOR " + numDaysWorked + " DAYS: " + formatter.format(totalPay));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double amount = 1; // make sure it initially equals 1

for (int daysWorked = 1; daysWorked <= numDaysWorked; daysWorked++) {

    System.out.println("Pay for day #" + daysWorked + ": " + formatter.format(amount));

    totalPay += amount; // add the amount value each time to the totalPay variable
    amount *= 2; // it doubles so just double it every loop
}

System.out.println("\nTOTAL PAY FOR " + numDaysWorked + " DAYS: " + formatter.format(totalPay));
```

Comment: Thank you!! This totally did it.

Answer (score 2):

```
       totalPay = ?? ;
```

should be

```
       totalPay = totalPay + amount; // adding each day pay to totalPay
```

or written in short form like this:

```
       totalPay +=  amount; // adding each day pay to totalPay
```

Your logic is buggy because first day pay will also be doubled due to the line :

```
       amount =  daysWorked * 2;
```

which you don't want. So you may add an if in your for loop to correct it:

```
for ( int daysWorked = 1; daysWorked <= numDaysWorked; daysWorked++) {

           System.out.println("Pay for day #" + daysWorked + ": " + formatter.format(amount));

           if(daysWorked == 1) {

              amount =  daysWorked 
           } else {

              amount =  daysWorked * 2;
           }
           totalPay +=  amount; // adding each day pay to totalPay 

         }
```

Comment: This is what I'm getting from the console:

Please enter the number of days you worked: 
3
Pay for day #1: $1.00
Pay for day #2: $2.00
Pay for day #3: $4.00

TOTAL PAY FOR 3 DAYS: $12.00

Comment: @user3003237 check the edited code in my answer and explanation of bug in your code.

Comment: I'd initialized my amount = 0; I'm getting the output: Pay for day #1: $1.00
Pay for day #2: $1.00
Pay for day #3: $4.00